# regex - Start to match after certain pattern

Tags: .net, regex

I'm having trouble when trying to find stuff with regex.

I have the following regex

```
([{\-\+~a-zA-Z0-9]+){3,}
```

And it works as it should, however, I need to capture all possible matches AFTER a certain character, which in this case is `}`.

```
faz.}a..sd..3·$....................foo....e..P...0...................bar
```

`foo` and `bar` must match, but `faz` shouldn't. Note that I can't use `.+(?=})` because it captures everything after the `}` into a single match. I searched in the internet and every answer suggested this pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the environment? Tool? Programming language? Try [`[-{+~a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}(?![^}]*})`](https://regex101.com/r/VrvICg/1)

Comment: I'm currently testing in Regex101 (pcre) and then I will implement it in C# if it's feasible.

Comment: Aha, using a wrong site then. PCRE is not the same as .NET regex. But the suggestion above will work the same in both flavors. In .NET, you may use [`(?<=}.*)[-{+~a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%7d.*%29%5b-%7b%2b%7ea-zA-Z0-9%5d%7b3%2c%7d&i=faz.%7da..sd..3%c2%b7%24....................foo....e..P...0...................bar), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET, you may use a positive variable length lookbehind to match the pattern occurrences only after a certain char/substring/pattern:

```
(?<=}.*)[-{+~a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}
^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%7D.*%29%5B-%7B%2B%7Ea-zA-Z0-9%5D%7B3%2C%7D&i=faz.%7Da..sd..3%C2%B7%24....................foo....e..P...0...................bar)

**Details**

- `(?<=}.*)` - a `}` (and any 0+ chars other than a newline) should be present before the subsequent cosuming pattern part
- `[-{+~a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}` - 3 or more occurrences of letters, digits and some punctuation/symbol chars listed in the character class.

You might also check an opposite approach: match the words you need if they are not followed with `}`:

```
[-{+~a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}(?![^}]*})
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B-%7B%2B%7Ea-zA-Z0-9%5D%7B3%2C%7D%28%3F!%5B%5E%7D%5D*%7D%29&i=faz.%7Da..sd..3%C2%B7%24....................foo....e..P...0...................bar).

Here, `(?![^}]*})` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `}` after any 0+ chars other than `}` immediately to the right of the "word" matched with the `[-{+~a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Get it all at once with a simplified and quicker *CaptureCollection*

`(?s)}(?:.*?([{\-+~a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}))+`

Read version

```
 (?s)
 }
 (?:
      .*? 
      ( [{\-+~a-zA-Z0-9]{3,} )      # (1)
 )+
```

C#

```
string inp = @"faz.}a..sd..3·$....................foo....e..P...0...................bar";
Regex Rx1 = new Regex( @"(?s)}(?:.*?([{\-+~a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}))+" );
Match M1 = Rx1.Match( inp );
if ( M1.Success )
{
    CaptureCollection cc = M1.Groups[1].Captures;
    for (int i = 0; i < cc.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", cc[i].Value);
}
```

Output

```
foo  
bar  
Press any key to continue . . .
```